# Atom Material Icons custom folders not working

Tags: visual-studio-code, icons

I like the Atom Material Icons extension more than the Material Icon Theme extension for VSCode.
But there is one problem. They don't have an icon for a folder called "auth" or "authorization".

I tried to read the docs and tried everything. But when I try to associate an "auth" folder with "security", nothing happens (it would be fine if it had the same icon).

However, I can add custom folder icons in Material Icon Theme, but can't override existing folder icons. And there, I have an auth folder, but I don't like the theme over all (because of the difference between open and closed folders).

Does anybody have an idea how to fix that or does anybody had the same issue too?

This is my settings.json

```
"a-file-icon-vscode.foldersAssociations": {
    "auth": "security",                         // This one should give "auth" folders the icon of "security"
    /* "auth": "../../icons/auth",              This path is given in the docs
    "auth": "../../../../icons/twitch"          This path worked in material-icon-theme */       
},
```